# Selecionar linhas por primeiros dígitos, e média delas por ano

Tags: python, pandas

Tenho um CSV do seguinte tipo:

```
code   year   sales
2011   1970   5000
2011   1971   5200
2011   1972   ...
...   
2015   1970
2015   1971
2015   1972
...
3025
...
3026
...
3052
...
```

Como posso selecionar todas as linhas de *code* que começam por '20', ou '30', e tirar a média de *sales* pra cada ano (*year*)?

Muito obrigado!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv, collections

soma = collections.defaultdict(float)
qtd = collections.defaultdict(int)

with open('arquivo.csv', newline='') as f:
    cf = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter='\t')
    for reg in cf:
        chave = (reg['code'], reg['year'])
        soma[chave] += float(reg['sales'])
        qtd[chave] += 1

for code, year in sorted(soma):
    print("A media para o code {} no ano {} é: {}".format(
         code, year, soma[code, year] / qtd[code, year]
    )
```

Comment: Não fui muito claro, desculpa. Quero tirar a média de todos os 'code' que comecem por '20' (i.e. 2011 2015...) em cada ano. Em 1970 pra cada 'code' uma média, e assim por diante pra todos os anos. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: @R.Moura se a sua pergunta não está boa, **edite a pergunta** e coloque mais informações, exemplos de entrada, exemplo de como você quer que fique no final - tipo seria útil pra quem está respondendo se você colocasse umas 10 linhas e um exemplo de como ficaria o resultado se seu arquivo fosse somente essas 10 linhas.